# Deinit not getting called for viewController when textField becomes firstResponder. It calls Deinit If textField is not made first responder

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I am facing a weird behavior with textfield becoming the first responder. I have added keyboard observer in ViewWillAppear and removed in viewWillDisappear. Whenever I don't make textField first responder Deinit of ViewController gets called but whenever TextField becomes the first responder, Deinit is not getting called on dismissing of the keyboard.
I know this is unusual but has anybody faced this? This is how code looks like-

```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ZLOTPBaseVC.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ZLOTPBaseVC.keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}


   override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide)

}
```

Comment: Please show your `keyboardWillShow` and `keyboardWillHide` functions.

Comment: Even I tried with empty implementation of keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide methods. Deinit doesn't get called.